# PowerBI / PowerQuery: Date slicer for multiple tables

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, powerquery, relationships, powerbi-desktop

Fellow PowerBI enthusiasts,

I am working on a reporting tool for our support team within our company. They would like to see the hours worked for each operator on a specific selection of dates. This could be just one day, or the whole week.

There are three different kinds of tasks that can be logged. Either time spent on Changes, on Incidents or on Operations (Change-, Incident- and OperationsActivityTimeRegistrations). There is a relationship between these registration tables and the operators table to show the full names in the PowerBI Dashboard, but there is one problem:

I cannot make a proper slicer for the dates. If I select one of the dates from a ___TimeRegistrations table, it will only filter on the dates for that table. That's why we made a new table called 'Datum' which contains all the dates from 1-1-2018 till 31-12-2019 and use those as input for my slicer, but I cannot make a link.

A picture of the relationships: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Ord.jpg

A picture of the report: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGMXI.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Kind Regards,

Sander

Comment: What do you mean you "cannot make a link"?. You need to link your date (calendar) table to the three fact tables. Google 'calendar table'

Comment: That was indeed a bit unclear. I have already tried what you are suggesting, but I can only activate one of the relationships between the fact tables and the date tables. When I try to activate the others, I get an error concerning the ambiguity between the tables 'Datum' and 'Operators'.

Comment: The date table should not be joined to operators - only the other three

Comment: The date table is not in a direct relationship with the operators table. The current relationship I'm trying to set is shown in this picture https://imgur.com/a/b4E9t1A

I cannot activate the two relationships that are shown in the picture as dotted line.

Comment: 2 questions: 1) why are all relationships to "operators" table bi-directional? You are hurting your model for (seemingly) no reason.  2) What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: I did not think the bi-directional relationship would be a problem, but it was! I fixed it. 

The error I get is in Dutch, because of my language preferences.The error is the same as http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/ambiguity-between-tables/m-p/343946, but with a different cause